# How to make div width equal to viewport width, but scalable (user-scalable=yes) in HTML5

Tags: html, cordova

I am working on application in Phonegap (essentially mobile browser wrapped around HTML5 page), that need their initial width to be equal viewport width when started, but allow user for rescale. So far I've tried:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0, user-scalable=yes" />
(...)
<img src="foo.jpg" style="width:100%" />
```

Didn't work, on Android 2.2 and 2.3 - it scaled img while user scaled viewport via gesture

And:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0, user-scalable=yes" />
(...)
<img src="foo.jpg" style="width:480px" />
```

This also didn't work on Android - it produced img of about 4/3 of viewport size on start (so user was able to scroll right).

I am probably missing something obvious, but searching Google so far didn't gave results I want

**EDIT**: It seems to be bug in PhoneGap, second code is working outside PhoneGap

Comment: Hm, this seems to be bug in Phonegap (http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/problems_with_viewport_configuration_for_android)

Comment: I blogged about something similar, can you use this kind of solution? http://bravenewmethod.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/html5-canvas-layout-and-mobile-devices/

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS + Phonegap = Not rendering correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414158/css-phonegap-not-rendering-correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in Phonegap (2012). It is long fixed since then :)