# CSS + Phonegap = Not rendering correctly

Tags: android, css, cordova, render

I'm facing a problem that i've been fighting from a long time, but i still don't have an answer. I looked for it in tons of foruns and websites, but nothing really works. Anyone faced the same problem and solved it?

The problem: I have a page with multiple divs on it, and each div is a page. Everytime i click on a button, one of the divs get visible and the others hidden. Here comes the problem: If i click multiple time on different links (to change the visible div), it stops rendering the correct content and blocks in one of them. I noticed that the contect is loaded, just don't render on the screen. I noticed it, because if i turn the cellphone in landscape and then in portrait, the content renders correctly and shows what i wanted.

Seems that this error occurs because the phone doesn't render the content properly. Is there a way to solve it? Maybe forcing the renderization? How can i make it? i couldn't find anything.

I looked and tried tons of codes, the one that worked for me was using the followind css, but it brings me a lot of problem. The textboxes start moving when i type and sometimes it doesnt accept some characters, and many other strange problems.

The code: `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);`

I'm using in my html files the following code also: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`. It allows me to have fixed header without using any js library.

The tools i'm using: Phonegap 2.5, android 2.3.4

Any idea?

Thank you

PS: I decided to don't publish the code, because it doesn't seem to be related with what i write, but with some bug..

Answer (score 1):

I think if I remember correctly the Android 2.3x browsers do not support translate3d
that should be the problem try running it on a 4.x AVD and see if it works

Comment: yes, Max.. Android 2.3 doesn't support it. This is why i am trying to change it for something. Do you now any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

This guy solved the problem:

[Android WebView renders blank/white, view doesn't update on css changes or HTML changes, animations are choppy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500452/android-webview-renders-blank-white-view-doesnt-update-on-css-changes-or-html?rq=1)

Seems that its the only way to solve it properly, i didn't find anything but this solution...

Comment: I noticed that this solution doesn't solve everything. Still shows some problems. =/

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to this, and the bug was caused because i was using "css content" property (content: '';).

If you are using this, try to remove.

best,